# Android widgets size - what if non-standard size is used?

Tags: android, android-widget

Understand that 1x1 widget size should be 72 dip x 72 dip, but this is seems to be less than standard icon size. If I change size to 80 dip x 80 dip, then it looks as the same. Is it OK if I would use this size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html):

> The default Home screen positions App
>   Widgets in its window based on a grid
>   of cells that have a defined height
>   and width. If the values for an App
>   Widget's minimum width or height don't
>   match the dimensions of the cells,
>   then the App Widget dimensions round
>   up to the nearest cell size. (See the
>   App Widget Design Guidelines for more
>   information on the Home screen cell
>   sizes.)
>
> Because the Home screen's layout
>   orientation (and thus, the cell sizes)
>   can change, as a rule of thumb, you
>   should assume the worst-case cell size
>   of 74 pixels for the height and width
>   of a cell. However, you must subtract
>   2 from the final dimension to account
>   for any integer rounding errors that
>   occur in the pixel count.

Those instructions are for "the default Home screen". Other home screen implementations may behave differently. If your widget layout and such will work well both at the regular size and your slightly larger size, in principle your 80dip will work -- just understand that your request for 8dip of additional space will typically be ignored.

Personally, I would use 72dip, to ensure compatibility.